# Kryo classloader issue

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I have  2 applications :
Application1 Serializes a Javaobject using Kryo serializer and application2 deserializes kryo serialized byte[] saved by application1 on external storage.

Application1 has kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar in its classpath and application2 has kryo-shaded-4.0.1 in its classpath.

When application2 tries to deserilze the byte[] it gets the exception : 
kryo unable to load class with kryo's classloader retrying with current .

When I change the version of kryo in application1 also as kryo-shaded-4.0.1. It works fine. Why is there an issue when serializer has different version.
Who sets the kryo classloader ?

Comment: You would expect the serialization format to be different across major kryo versions. As such, you need to use the same major version at least for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

## Why is there an issue when the serializer has a different version?

When Kryo serializes data into a byte array, it packs the contents of the object into a particular format. The exact way in which Kryo packs data into byte arrays various across different versions of Kryo. So if you serialize data with version 3.0.3 the format will be different from the format expected by version 4.0.1. So if you send bytes to the receiver in a format he doesn't understand, you can't expect him to process the data correctly.

## Who sets the kryo classloader?

I'm not sure about the internals of Kryo but I think it probably uses the same classloader as the thread that is running your code by default. You may be able to set an alternative classloader if you want but you'd have to check the docs.

The exception you observed `kryo unable to load class with Kryo's classloader retrying with current` is likely caused because the receiver misread the byte array sent to him. For example if the sender sent a byte array with contents `com.my.class.TestXXXXXXX` where the class name is at the beginning, but the receiver expected the class name to be at the end and read the class name as `XXXXXXX`. Then Kryo will use the class loader to find the class `XXXXXXX`, but he will fail because there is no class `XXXXXXX`. Why does Kryo on the receiver need to lookup the class in the first place? Because he needs to instantiate the Object you sent, and in order to do that he needs to call the no-arg constructor of the Object's Class.